# Server 2012 RemoteApp install

Tags: windows-server-2012, remoteapp

I am trying to install a simple RemoteApp install on a Windows 2012 server but am getting a bit confused by the different components and what is and is not required.

Is 'Remote Desktop Gateway' required in this senario?  The RemoteApps reside on the same Application Server so no Internet access to other internal machines is necessary.

My current problem is that Server Manager -> Remote Desktop Services displays the following error:
A Remote Desktop Services deployment does not exist in the server pool.  To create a deployment, run the Add Roles and Features Wizard and select the Remote Desktop Services installation option.

However we don't want to use Remote Desktop Services installation because we are not setting up any sort of Virtual Desktop Infrastructure.  So question is how do we add a Remote Desktop Services deployment to the server pool with out using Remote Desktop Services installation?

Answer (score 4):

Remote Desktop Services is still used to deliver RemoteApps. You must have the requisite CALs for RDS and you must properly configure it for RemoteApp to function. RDS isn't just for virtual desktops.

I recommend reading through [the RemoteApp documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755055.aspx) before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks but the documentation suggested refers to Server 2008 rather than Server 2012.  It seem that Server 2012 is a bit different.  Have not been able to find and docunemtation on how to do this in Server 2012.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what makes you think that you can do RemoteApp without RDS on Server 2012? Some of the RemoteApp features have changed, but the fundamentals are still the same. You still need to install and configure at least one Remote Desktop Session Host and it must be properly licensed for each RemoteApp user, even if you aren't having users RDP directly to the server.

Comment: Already got Remote Desktop Session Host installed along with Remote Desktop Connection Broker and Remote Desktop WebAccess.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screen capture]

You just need to select in add Roles & features this option.

And then:
[image]